# How to skip files with read error in it when copying with rsync on Linux?

Tags: rsync

I'm copying files from my sda to my sdb.  sda have read errors on it, which means that when a files is written on a read error block, reading this file provokes several read error which freeze the system.

I would like rsync to skip those files, keeping the old file on sdb intact.  No problem, I am prepared to possibly loose my latest files.

Is it possible to skip files with read errors? How can I do?

Thank for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way for rsync to gracefully recover from hardware errors. Your best bet would be to do a block-level copy of the device with something like [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html). The "rescued" copy could then be rsync'd, or used as is.